# Normal HD on Ultra Wide Monitor without Stretching Pixels

Tags: arch-linux, xrandr, resolution

Often, when recording in OBS, I would like to have a normal screen resolution (HD) so I can capture the screen in the more normal 1920x1080 format. However, if I do something like:

```bsh
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080
```

My PC will simply stretch out the 1920 pixels to fit the ultra-wide monitor's width, which is visually annoying and pretty much useless.

Is there a way of having the 1920 pixels use the standard size for my monitor? Maybe there's something in `xrandr` I'm missing?

> I'm using Artix OpenRC — a distro based on Arch.