# how to not stretch the 4:3 (1024x768) resolution on a wide monitor (1920x1080)?

Tags: resolution, framebuffer, nomodeset

I need this because my dell notebook video card is only not freezing if I use nomodeset on grub.
But then, I am limited to 4:3 resolutions (right?).
So, I am looking for a way to not stretch the screen image (1024x768) on the full resolution (1920x1080) monitor.
I wanted to let the 1024x768 (or 1440x1080) be in the middle of the screen (with a black margin on each side), not stretching!
I cant find a way to command xrandr to do that, I tried many things on the --output and --pos but nothing help to accomplish that.

Even better would be if there was some way to tell VESA to use 1920x1080 directly tho.

related:
[Normal HD on Ultra Wide Monitor without Stretching Pixels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644634/normal-hd-on-ultra-wide-monitor-without-stretching-pixels)

wont work:
https://askubuntu.com/a/614242/46437
https://superuser.com/a/1245757/157532 (for 2 monitors, not my case)
https://superuser.com/a/485165/157532 :(
...

Comment: nvidia has a viewportout thing like `nvidia-settings -a CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0: 1920x1080 {viewportout=1850x1040+35+19}"` https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=342636, but the notebook is intel video card

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644634/normal-hd-on-ultra-wide-monitor-without-stretching-pixels ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1316838/226614 and other answers

Comment: I thought I could make a better question (thats why I said it is just related) as that one got no answers and was missing several things I wanted to talk about. Also I ask about a direct VESA option, and I dismiss stuff about 2 monitors that is what everyone else seems to want to talk about. I still need to test the scaling and panning possibilities to know if that second link answers it, I cant use the notebook right now.

Comment: Stretching lower resolutions is typically a feature of the monitor